# in chained functions, which one executes first?

Tags: javascript

say I have an array of elements and I want to sort them, and filter them. I can do it in two ways:

```
let Result = MyArray.sort((a,b) => {
        return b.sortingNum - a.sortingNum
    }).filter((task) => {
        return !task.isWanted
    }
);
```

or

```
let Result = MyArray.filter((task) => {
        return !task.isWanted
    }).sort((a,b) => {
        return b.sortingNum - a.sortingNum
    }
);
```

Two questions:

- in first approach, which one executes first? the `sort` or `filter`?
- What is better in respect to the O-Notation? do I sort then filter, or filter then sort. I would go for filter then sort since filter requires less processing power for bigger data. But just throwing the Q here and learn more.

Thanks

Comment: They always execute in the order they appear, but I think you might be a little fooled by `sort`, as it sorts "in place".

Comment: The functions are executed in the order you call them.

Comment: @adeneo In my code I actually `return` the whole statement, but maybe the edit is helpful. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first approach the sort function would execute first and then filter.

Complexity wise, the 2nd approach would be better since we would apply sort on an array of a shorter length(after filtering). While on the other hand, filter would take the same time complexity.

Comment: Hi sorry what do you mean by "_while filter would take the same time_"?

Comment: Since it would be O(n) in both cases. It would iterate all objects. But sorting would happen with fewer elements if filtered first

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example, with printing for each step of the way:

```js
var MyArray = [
  {sortingNum: 10, isWanted: true}, 
  {sortingNum: 12, isWanted: true}, 
  {sortingNum: 2, isWanted: false}, 
  {sortingNum: 8, isWanted: true}, 
  {sortingNum: 11, isWanted: false}, 
  {sortingNum: 6, isWanted: false}, 
  {sortingNum: 7, isWanted: true}
];
console.log(
  MyArray.sort((a, b) => {
    console.log("sorting");
    return b.sortingNum - a.sortingNum
  }).filter((task) => {
    console.log("filtering");
    return !task.isWanted
  })
);

console.log(
  MyArray.filter((task) => {
    console.log("filtering");
    return !task.isWanted
  }).sort((a, b) => {
    console.log("sorting");
    return b.sortingNum - a.sortingNum
  })
);
```

As you can clearly see, the chained functions will execute in order of appearance. Basically, the last function will be applied to the result of the previous etc.

As far as complexity is concerned, the optimal way would be to first `.filter()` the array, then apply the `.sort()`ing, based on the fact that filtering removes some elements, thus making the sorting have to execute less comparison operations than sorting the whole array and then removing unnecessary elements.
In the above example, you can either sort 7 elements, then pick out the 3 you want *or* pick the 3 that you want and then sort these 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyArray.sort(...).filter(...);
```

is equivalent to

```
var sorted = MyArray.sort(...);
var filtered = sorted.filter(...);
```

So you see how `filter` will execute on the result of `sort`, and therefore necessitates that `sort`executes first?